# Верно ли употреблено слово "палладиум" в цитате?

Tags: выбор-слов

> В IX веке получает распространение своеобразная «мода» на мощи святых.
>   Всякая церковь и всякий католик жаждет иметь священную частичку,
>   множество людей по собственной корысти или по заказу сторонних
>   епископов шарят в гробах, расхищая кости и всё драгоценное. *Это
>   понудило римлян охранять принадлежащие городу мощи больше, чем стены
>   города. Гордые обладанием такой святыни, какой не было ни в какой
>   другой церкви всего мира, римляне видели в этих мощах палладиум Рима и
>   также тот магнит, который привлекал к себе пилигримов из всех стран.*

До курсива идёт текст, который я редактирую, далее цитата, в которой меня очень смутило в*и*дение в мощах палладиум Рима...

Это Грегоровиус Фердинанд » История города Рима в Средние века:
http://bukabooks.com/kniga/17386/istoriya-goroda-rima-v-srednie-veka/page-147

О книге:

*Впервые в одном томе выходит в свет фундаментальный труд знаменитого немецкого историка и культуролога Фердинанда Грегоровиуса (1821—1891) «История города Рима в Средние века». В этом уникальном по своей полноте произведении автор с немецким педантизмом и скрупулезностью последовательно год за годом, столетие за столетием описывает события римской истории (многие из которых малоизвестны современному читателю) и их культурологический контекст. Благодаря широте охвата исторического материала, а также литературному таланту автора это произведение стало классическим образцом исторического исследования, посвященного эпохе Средних веков и Раннего Возрождения. Книга читается не как скучный исторический трактат, а как литературное произведение с захватывающим сюжетом, что делает ее интересной широкому кругу читателей.*

Переводчики М. Литвинов, В. Линде, В. Савин... Кто-то из них мог быть и неточен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**палладиум**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%83%D0%BC)
*перен.* *устар.* защита, оплот
*Французский король обещал свое содействие английскому в великом деле утверждения самодержавия и уничтожения неприкосновенной святыни народной: палладиума его могущества ― конституционной хартии.*
П. П. Каратыгин, «Временщики и фаворитки 16, 17 и 18 столетий», 1870 г.

*У Вацлава был верный слуга Подивен. Его имя связано с Палладиумом - священным предметом, охраняющем Чешскую землю от врагов.*
[**Мистическая Прага**](http://prahafx.narod.ru/sacred/mystic/mystic3.htm)

*Вся Франция беги за нами в бой!

В залоге честь, обругана корона;

Разрушена престола оборона;

В руках врага палладиум святой...*

Я думаю, что все правильно. Слово употреблено в переносном значении — оберег.

Answer (score 2):

Палладиум, палладий (др.-греч. παλλάδιον) — священная статуя-оберег, изображавшая Афину-Палладу. Являлась святыней и талисманом города, в котором хранилась.

В переносном смысле — **талисман, сакральный предмет,** приносящий удачу владельцу (чаще стране).

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%83%D0%BC

Comment: То есть *талисман* Рима? Всё в порядке?

Comment: Да, талисман Рима, именно это значение.